# Is there any way to interact between ink smart contract and off-chain worker?

Tags: pallet, ink, runtime, offchain-worker

I know that we can interact between smart contract and runtime (and vice versa) but I can not find a way that I can fetch data from API (in off-chain worker pallet) and pass those data to the smart contract (written by ink).

Do you guys have any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there might not be any way to fetch data from API (off-chain worker pallet) and pass those data to the ink smart contract but there is [phala network](https://wiki.phala.network/en-us/general/phala-network/intro/) where they have done `Phat Contract Oracle Workshop` which you can find [here](https://github.com/Phala-Network/phat-offchain-rollup/blob/main/phat/Sub0-Workshop.md#phat-contract-oracle-workshop).

> After this workshop, you will learn:
>
> 1. What the Phat Contract offchain computing is and how it can help build
>    oracles.
> 2. Fetch and process arbitrary data with HTTP(s) requests
> 3. Integrate to a Substrate blockchain
> 4. `Implement the oracle in ink!`

There are two section section two will coming soon. Tho it's incomplete but still Phat contract or phala network is the way to to fetch off-chain data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already known about Phat Contract but it is not the thing that I am finding as my data may be exposed to the world I think.